# google apps script session id google sites

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

My girlfriend has a small business making cupcakes, cookies, cake pops, etc. and I want to create a relatively simple website for her. The website would have several pages with photos of different items people can order. Essentially I would like the site to act like a shopping cart, but instead of placing an order, it is just for getting a quote. My idea is that whenever they add something to the quote, the apps script will save the details to a spreadsheet. When they have finished and want to get their quote, they click a submit button which will send an email with the details that have been stored in the spreadsheet.

I can work out how to do almost everything required, except that I can't work out how to get some kind of session ID to link the records that I'm adding to the spreadsheet. Is there some way to retrieve a unique session ID that would accomplish what I'm after? Is what I'm doing even possible with Google Sites and Google Apps Script? Has anybody successfully done something similar? Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can track the user's email address and use it as the key if they are a signed in Google user, and perhaps track the last time they've visited the script as well if you want "sessions" to clear after 24 hours, etc. There is no way to get a key for non-signed-in Google users. Also, consider UserProperties or ScriptDb for this instead of a spreadsheet.

Comment: in the documentation it is stated that you can only retrieve the email address of other users on your domain: "we only return the identity of the active user if both the user and the script owner are part of the same domain. This is to protect the privacy of consumer users, who may not want their email address exposed." Has it changed ?

Comment: Nope, that is still true. If you are looking for a broader solution, store a random string in UserProperties and use that as the identity of the user going forward; it will be tied to the user's email address (as long as they are a Google user) even though it won't tell you what that address is.

Comment: This `UserProperties` does not serve when the script is published as a webapp with access to anyone even anonymous. According to this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13158927/1408731) there is nothing like near to a solution for this.